# Intel-base Assembly Language Segmentation Fault

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault

Every time I try to run my code I get a Segmentation Fault. Can anyone point me in the right direction at what can be causing this?

Compiler is on Linux that I'm running the code from via PuTTY.

I think it has to do with `mov dword [esp + #]` but don't know about fixing it.

```
%include "asm_io.inc"
segment .data
display db "Area: %d | Points: %d | Probability: %d/%d",10,0
display2 db "Expected Outsome: %d", 0
radiusone db "Enter number ", 0
radiustwo db "Enter number ", 0
radiusthree db "Enter number ", 0
radiusfour db "Enter number ", 0
pointsone db "Enter number ", 0
pointstwo db "Enter number ", 0
pointsthree db "Enter number ", 0
pointsfour db "Enter number ", 0

segment .bss

r1 resd 1 ;Radius
r2 resd 1
r3 resd 1
r4 resd 1
p1 resd 1 ;Points
p2 resd 1
p3 resd 1
p4 resd 1
ca1 resd 1 ;Computed Area
ca2 resd 1
ca3 resd 1
ca4 resd 1
pi1 resd 1 ;radius*radius
pi2 resd 1
pi3 resd 1
pi4 resd 1
pb1 resd 1 ;Probability
pb2 resd 1
pb3 resd 1
pb4 resd 1
eo resd 1 ; Expected Outcome

segment .text
        global  asm_main
        extern printf
asm_main:
        enter   0,0            
        pusha

    mov eax, radiusone
    call print_string
    call read_int
    mov [r1], eax

    mov eax, radiustwo
    call print_string
    call read_int
    mov [r2], eax

    mov eax, radiusthree
    call print_string
    call read_int
    mov [r3], eax

    mov eax, radiusfour
    call print_string
    call read_int
    mov [r4], eax
    ;************************

    mov eax, pointsone
    call print_string
    call read_int
    mov [p1], eax

    mov eax, pointstwo
    call print_string
    call read_int
    mov [p2], eax

    mov eax, pointsthree
    call print_string
    call read_int
    mov [p3], eax

    mov eax, pointsfour
    call print_string
    call read_int
    mov [p4], eax
    ;************************

    mov eax, [r1]
    imul eax, [r1]
    mov [pi1], eax 

    mov eax, [r2]
    imul eax, [r2]
    mov [pi2], eax 

    mov eax, [r3]
    imul eax, [r3]
    mov [pi3], eax 

    mov eax, [r4]
    imul eax, [r4]
    mov [pi4], eax 
    ;**********************

    mov eax, [r1]
    mov [ca1], eax

    mov eax, [ca2]
    sub eax, [pi1]
    mov [ca2], eax 

    mov eax, [ca3]
    sub eax, [pi2]
    mov [ca3], eax 

    mov eax, [ca4]
    sub eax, [pi3]
    mov [ca4], eax 
    ;********************

    mov eax, [r1]
    imul eax, [p1]
    mov [pb1], eax

    mov eax, [r2]
    imul eax, [p2]
    mov [pb2], eax

    mov eax, [r3]
    imul eax, [p3]
    mov [pb3], eax

    mov eax, [r4]
    imul eax, [p4]
    mov [pb4], eax
    ;***********************

    mov eax, [pb1]
    add eax, [pb2]
    add eax, [pb3]
    add eax, [pb4]
    mov [eo], eax
    ;************************

    sub easp 10h

    push dword [pi4]
    push dword [ca1]
    push dword [p1]
    push dword [r1]


    mov dword [esp], display
    call printf
    add esp, 10h    


    popa
    mov     eax, 0           
    leave                     
    ret
```

**Update: I added changes to the code with the use of pop function down where the call is and now it does get rid of the segmentation fault and I now get output, however, not the values I'd like.**

**output:**

*Area: 134520364 | Points: 134520380 | Probability: 134520396/134520424*

*Area: 134520260 | Points: 134520276 | Probability: 134520292/134520320*

*Area: 134520260 | Points: 134520276 | Probability: 134520292/134520320*

**when it should be**

*Area: 1 | Points: 17 | Probability: 1/64*

I don't have a loop set so I'm unsure why 3 lines have been printed.

**UPDATE2:**

**Made changes to the push by suggestion made I know get output looking better...**

*Area: 17 | Points: 1 | Probability: 64/134519817*

**Even though should be:**

*Area: 1 | Points: 17 | Probability: 1/64*

**how I have it in stack**

**1 , 17 , 1 , 64.... and my string for it is:**

*display db "Area: %d | Points: %d | Probability: %d/%d",10,0*

**So it looks like they are randomly placed**

**Do I need to add the** `mov dword [esp + 4], display` **?**

Comment: It looks like you are just moving parameters onto the stack for your `printf` call. You can't do that since you are overwriting other items on the stack. You have to `push` parameters onto the stack, make the call, then restore the stack pointer to where it was before you did the pushes.

Comment: I did what you said and it got rid of the segmentation fault and it has given me output though incorrect output. I looked over my code and not sure why its given me those numbers. I can only speculate those numbers are memory locations?

Answer (score 2):

The seg fault comes from improperly exiting your program.  `ret` is not the proper way to exit your program in Linux or Windows.  Windows it is `ExitProcess` and Linux is is system call, or a call to `exit` from the C library.  In your case, you are linking to the C Library to use `printf` and gcc will add startup code that gets run before your code, so you must call `exit` to properly terminate your program.

There are others issues, but this will fix the seg fault.  Also, do as mbratch mentioned and pass parameters by pushing and adjusting esp after the call to printf

Answer (score 0):

First off, the `mov dword [esp + #], ...` lines are overwriting what the `push ...` lines do, so you should get rid of those. Second, those numbers you're outputting look like addresses - indeed, when you do i.e. `push pi4`, you're pushing the address of the `pi4` variable. Instead, you should push the contents of the variable, with `push dword [pi4]`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm on the right track now. Going to update. Still little mixed but still work in progress